# How to add members to a group using directory api and python?

Tags: python, google-directory-api

I am trying to get my head around migrating to google admin sdk. I am trying to add members to a group (mailing list) using python. I have figured out how to create the group, but can't figure out how to add members. I have read this page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert but cannot figure out how to map it to python (I have little experience with REST or python, I'm trying to learn).

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

keyFile = file(p12File, 'rb')
key = keyFile.read()
keyFile.close()
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(serviceAccount,
  key,
  scope,
  prn=superAdmin)

http = httplib2.Http()
httplib2.debuglevel = False #change this to True if you want to see the output
http = credentials.authorize(http=http)
directoryService = build(serviceName='admin', version='directory_v1', http=http)


# THIS DOES NOT WORK
groupinfo = {'email': 'wibble@XXX.co.uk'}
directoryService.groups().insert(groupKey='mygroup@XXX.co.uk', body=groupinfo).execute()
```

When I run that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add-member-to-group.py", line 58, in <module>
    directoryService.groups().insert(groupKey='mygroup@XXX.co.uk', body=groupinfo).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 604, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument "%s"' % name)
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "groupKey"
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 7):

After further hunting around I worked it out. That last line should have been:

```
directoryService.members().insert(groupKey='mygroup@XXX.co.uk', body=groupinfo).execute()
```

i.e. directoryService.**members**()... not directoryService.**groups**()...

The examples [here](https://github.com/alfasin/Google-Admin-Directory-API) helped me to work it out.